# Ubuntu on Windows GUI interface sizing issues with text editors

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sublime-text-3, vcxsrv

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my Windows 10 machine using WSL2. I have also installed VcXsrv to use XLaunch to enable GUI environments to open. I updated the high DPI settings found here: [Blurry fonts on using Windows default scaling with WSL GUI applications (HiDPI)](https://superuser.com/questions/1370361/blurry-fonts-on-using-windows-default-scaling-with-wsl-gui-applications-hidpi), which updated fonts to be not blurry, as well as modifying some text sizing using the 2 `GDK_` commands.

After this, I still had some GUI sizing issues. Namely, the mouse and some UI elements were *very* small. I was able to fix the tiny mouse cursor by using this: [How do I set the size of the X mouse pointer in the Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/1196399/how-do-i-set-the-size-of-the-x-mouse-pointer-in-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux)

I still have one problem persisting: some UI elements are still super tiny. Below are examples of what I'm seeing.

**Sublime Text**

1. Very tiny tab and tab label, especially compared with the File/Edit/Selection line

[image: EX1]

2. Tiny line number.

[image: EX2]

3. Tiny tab size/language area.

[image: EX3]

**GEDIT**

4. Tiny x-button.

[image: EX4]

**Spyder**

5. Tiny file icons.

[image: EX5]

The desired look would be to, for example, have the tab text match the rest of the system size (and most likely then increase the tab size to accommodate this) in Sublime Text.

Much appreciated if anyone can help! I've tried looking for solutions both on Stack and elsewhere, but couldn't find anything. If this problem was already solved, please let me know and I'll close out this question.

Happy to clarify any points made here.

Comment: You will need to find what is causing the problem (maybe one of the solutions). I remember solving the same problem without that much fuss but ages ago.

Answer (score 1):

***Not my answer*** *provided by @kas*

You can find your DPI with this command:

```
xrdb query | grep dpi
```

You can set your DPI by creating the file ~/.Xresources with this content:

```
Xft.dpi: 96
```

Replace 96 with your desired DPI.

If you have GnomeTweaks that will be easy or will have to find its own Desktop Environment Utilities.

> Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/197828/how-to-find-and-change-the-screen-dpi

***Also check @whtyger answer for more info.***